# "phonegap run ios" command throws error after xcode upgraded to 6.0.1 on phonegap 3.5.0-0.21.17

Tags: cordova

Although the build succeeded, i see the following error when i execute phonegap run command

```
2014-09-23 16:44:47.925 ios-sim[6274:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ac3c13d50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8b51b25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff8b213e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8b51e12d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8b479272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
4 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8b478df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5 ios-sim 0x000000010fdb7e29 -[iPhoneSimulator LoadSimulatorFramework:] + 245
6 ios-sim 0x000000010fdb98e0 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 2271
7 ios-sim 0x000000010fdb9cb2 main + 101
8 ios-sim 0x000000010fdb7ce4 start + 52
9 ??? 0x000000000000000b 0x0 + 11
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
/Users/MyName/Sites/phonegap/helloworld/platforms/ios/cordova/run: line 158: 6274 Abort trap: 6 ios-sim launch "$SIMULATOR_APP_PATH" --stderr "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" --stdout "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" $TARGET_FLAG --exit
```

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update ios-sim:

```
npm install -g ios-sim
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

Comment: I had that before, but wasn't working. Anyway, reinstalling ios-sim solved this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ios-sim 3.0.0 is needed for Xcode 6+, update your ios-sim.